# HTML input type=file getting unexpected duplicate filenames on Google Chrome in Android 7 (Samsung SM-T580)

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, file-upload

I am getting unexpected duplicate filenames in the list of files selected by the user when they select multiple photos to upload in Google Chrome on Android 7 when tested on the Samsung SM-T580 tablet.

There aren't duplicate file names in the folder being uploaded from. This is especially apparent when the user selects more than 10 photos at once, say when they Select All from the photo selector dialog.

No other browsers I've tested with exhibit that behaviour (except for iOS devices where all the filenames are the same, which I skip testing in this code)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function DoUpload() {

        $("#output").val("");

        var control = $("input[type=file]")[0];

        var seenFileNames = {};
        var duplicateFileName = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < control.files.length; i++) {

            var name = control.files[i].name;

            $("#output").val( $("#output").val() + name + "\n");

            // iOS devices upload all with the same name such as image.jpeg so ignore those names
            if (/^image\.\w+$/.test(name)) continue;

            if (seenFileNames[name]) {
                duplicateFileName = name;
                break;
            }
            seenFileNames[name] = true;
        }

        if (duplicateFileName != null) {
            alert("Error: this filename was in the upload muliple times: " + duplicateFileName);
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>

<input type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="DoUpload()" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.m4v">
<br/>
<textarea rows="20" cols="40" id="output"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

The unexpected duplicate issue seems to only affect Android 7. Here's the details from chrome://version

```
Google Chrome   64.0.3282.137 (Official Build) (32-bit)
Revision    c0e649dc6b7990e24daaee45fc1682e006f4f0ca-refs/branch-heads/3282@{#620}
OS  Android 7.0.0; SM-T580 Build/NRD90M
Google Play services    SDK=11200000; Installed=11975434; Access=1p
JavaScript  V8 6.4.388.41
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-T580 Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Safari/537.36
Command Line    --enable-pinch --enable-viewport --validate-input-event-stream --enable-longpress-drag-selection --touch-selection-strategy=direction --main-frame-resizes-are-orientation-changes --disable-composited-antialiasing --enable-dom-distiller --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --top-controls-show-threshold=0.27 --top-controls-hide-threshold=0.17
Executable Path No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in the Android 7/Samsung SM-T580 tablet. When testing on other sites such as Google Drive the device would also duplicate/replace files chosen for uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that this happens asynchronously... you should pass the file index in your loop to make sure you have a handle to the file instance. I would rewrite your code like this:

var name = control.files[i].name + i;